# Hudson Problems : Skipping watched dependency update for build

Tags: hudson

I am installing Hudson CI in Windows Server 2008. I have some issues when build are failure and these message appear..

> Skipping watched dependency update for build

How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

This message appears every time even when the builds are successful. I think the message is debug statement in the code so appears in the log.